# Google nearbyplaces api bounds not working

Tags: api, bounds

I want to search all the nearby places within a bounding box using e,g
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?bounds=41.35,-81.8|41.54,-81.5&key='mykey'

but received this:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Any idea on how to make the correct call?

Thanks